# Use of private header from outside its module error in CPTBorderedLayer.m of CorePlot

Tags: cocoapods, core-plot, xcode7.1

I upgraded to a new laptop with El Capitan, XCode 7.1, and Cocoapods 0.39.0.  When I check out an existing project that uses the CorePlot framework, run pod install, and build the project, I get the following error messages in the CPTBorderedLayer.m file of CorePlot:

```
Use of private header from outside its module: '_CPTBorderLayer.h'
Use of private header from outside its module: '_CPTMaskLayer.h'
```

Below is a snippet of my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'my_project' do
...
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git'
```

This project was compiling fine using Xcode 7.0 and cocoapods 0.37.2, but I'd really rather not downgrade everything unless there are no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has something to do with the way CocoaPods sets up the framework project. A temporary fix is to remove the `use_frameworks!` line from the pod file to let it build the dependencies as a static library.

Please report the problem on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues) and we'll see if this can be fixed.